# is it ok this connection string for access since any computer (using Internet)

Tags: c#, .net, connection, connection-string, database-connection

well I need to have access since another place (using internet) but I don't have another PC for I see if this is OK ... I do have the connection since here myself computer, but I am going to need if I have a connection since another computer to my database, or do you know any another form? (it is for a windows application)

here my class connection because you watch if it is ok..

```
namespace Coneccion
{
    class Conexion
    {
        public SqlConnection conectar()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server,1433;Failover Partner=ip;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=login; Password=password; Asynchronous Processing=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Network Library=dbmssocn;Workstation ID=pc;User Instance=False");
            return con;
        }

        public void EjecutarConsulta(SqlCommand comando)
        {
            comando.Connection.Open(); // abrimos la conexion
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery(); // ejecutamos la consulta
            comando.Connection.Close(); // y cerramos la conexion
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this code getting some error in another computer.

```
TrustServerCertificate=True
```

But rest of the code is OK.

Answer (score 0):

also

```
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()){
  cmd.Open();
  // do some query.
} // using will automatic close the command
```